# Converta número romano para arábico em VisualG

Tags: visualg

O sistema de numeração romana (ou números romanos) desenvolveu-se na Roma Antiga e utilizou-se em todo o seu Império. Neste sistema as cifras escrevem-se com determinadas letras, que representam os números. As letras são sempre maiúsculas, já que no alfabeto romano não existem as minúsculas, as letras são I, V, X, L, C, D e M. Sua tarefa é desenvolver um programa que converta números romanos para arábicos. As regras para a formação dos números romanos são apresentadas a seguir. Cada letra corresponde a um determinado valor: I = 1 V = 5 X = 10 L = 50 C = 100 D = 500 M = 1000. Agrupando as letras acima, podemos representar os números de acordo com um conjunto de regras: Com exceção de V, L e D, os outros numerais podem se repetir no máximo três vezes:

III = 3

XXX = 30

CCC = 300

MMM = 3000

Quando escritos à direita de numerais maiores, I, X e C somam-se aos valores dos primeiros:

VIII = 5 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 8

LXII = 50 + 10 + 1 + 1 = 62

CLVIII = 158

MCXX = 1000 + 100 + 10 + 10 = 1120

Mas se os numerais I, X e C estiverem à esquerda dos maiores, seus valores são subtraídos como, por exemplo, em:

IV = 5 - 1 = 4

IX = 10 - 1 = 9

XC = 100 - 10 = 90

Acho que sei como finalmente fazer primeiramente eu pegaria o valor em romano digitado, pegaria o tamanho da letra valor atribuído seria n tamanho da letra e desse tamanho da letra tiraria n-1, depois tentaria dividir a letra, não sei o comando no VisualG para separar as letras e criaria um variável para armazenar o separamento dessas letras nesse caso separador criaria outra variável nesse caso s e receberia zero depois faria um para onde i =0 e i tem que ser menor que o tamanho da letra nessa e iria somando por +1 depois abriria um se verificando se a divisão da letras separador = "M" então s= s+1000 e dentro desse se abriria outro se  e se se separador[i-1]= "C" então s= s-200, terminaria esse se depois abriria outro se verificando se separador = "D" então s=s+500 e dentro abriria outro se e se separador[i-1] = "C" então s=s-200 depois fecharia esse se e abriria outro se separador = "C" então s=s+100 e dentro desse se abriria outro se se separador[i-1] = "X" e então s=s-20 depois terminaria esse se e abriria outro se, se separador = "L" então s=s+50 dentro abriria outro se, se separador[i-1] = "X" então

s=s-20 depois terminaria esse se e abriria outro se, se separador="X" então s=s+10 abriria outro se, se separador[i-1] = "I" então s=s-2 depois fecharia esse se depois abriria outro se, se separador="V" então s=s+5 e dentro desse se abriria outro se, se separador[i-1] = "I" então s=s-2 fecharia esse se depois abriria outro se se separador = "I" então s=s+1

depois daria um escreval(s)

O problema está na hora de separar as letras qual o comando no VisualG para separar letra ou não tem?

O comando copia é útil somente se separar letra por letra porém falha na hora, por exemplo de copiar um número romano, eu eu tenho que já passar esse comando com parâmetros já pré-deficinidos copie desta casa até esta casa (romano;1;2), que no não teria como colocar todos os parâmetros para todos os números de 1 a 3999
Por enquanto o código está assim

```
Var
   // Seção de Declarações das variáveis
   vetromano:vetor[1..9] de caractere
   romano:caractere
   i:inteiro
   m,c,d,u:caractere
   soma:inteiro


Inicio
   // Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc...
   escreval("Digite um número em romano para ser convertido em arábico")
   escreval("menor que 4000 e maior que 0")
   leia(romano)
   m <- copia(romano;1;2)
   c <- copia(romano;3;2)
   d <- copia(romano;5;2)
   u <- copia(romano;7;2)
   para i de 1 ate Compr(romano) faca
      se (m = "M") entao
         soma<-soma+1000
         se(m-1) entao
            soma<-soma-200
         fimse
      fimse

      escreval(soma)

   fimpara
   escreval
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto, espero que ajude:

algoritmo﻿﻿﻿ "Exemplo2"
var
   vetCarac :vetor [1..9] de caractere
   texto    :caractere
   i        :﻿inteiro
inicio
texto <- "MXLVIII"
para i de 1 ate Compr(texto) faca﻿
   vetCarac[i] <- Copia(texto,i,1)
fimPara
para i de 1 ate Co﻿﻿mpr(texto) faca
   escreval(vetCarac[i])
fimPara﻿
fimAlgoritmo﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿